# Horizontally centering a child element with no set width inside a parent with a constrained width

Tags: html, css, layout

I have a set of divs which act as markers. At the foot of the marker I have numbers. I'd like to center these numbers but the challenge so far is doing it within a div with a constrained width of 4px.

I managed to accomplish this by explicitly giving the span tags a set width, positioning them `left: 50%`, with a negative `margin-left: -20px` (half its width) and lastly `text-align: center`. Although it works it seems a bit *hacky* because in the event the number breaks outside the span the horizontal alignment doesn't work.

```css
.parent {
    background: black;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 30px;
    position: relative;
    height: 20px;
    width: 4px;
}

.child {
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -20px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -20px;
    width: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <span class="child">1</span>
</div>

<div class="parent">
    <span class="child">10</span>
</div>

<div class="parent">
    <span class="child">100</span>
</div>

<div class="parent">
    <span class="child">10000000</span>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm curious why the parent div is constrained to a width of 4px? It seems like maybe you're trying to layer one work-around on top of another possibly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a CSS3 `transform` on the child to bring it back 50% of it's own width.

```
.child {
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 50%;
    transform:translateX(-50%);

}
```

```css
.parent {
  background: black;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 30px;
  position: relative;
  height: 20px;
  width: 4px;
}
.child {
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <span class="child">1</span>
</div>

<div class="parent">
  <span class="child">10</span>
</div>

<div class="parent">
  <span class="child">100</span>
</div>

<div class="parent">
  <span class="child">10000000</span>
</div>
```

Support is IE9 and up - [**CanIUse.com**](http://caniuse.com/#feat=transforms2d)

Comment: Absolutely, `margin-top` will still work - http://jsfiddle.net/Paulie_D/6w485cbc/

Comment: Great thank you! Found out you could use `margin-top` just as I posted the comment.

Comment: Also worth noting `text-align: center` isn't needed. Removed it and had no affect on the outcome.

Comment: No, I just did a quick copy and paste. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can have your child code as:

```
.child {
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -20px;
    left: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateX(-50%);
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

This will centre your numbers. The problem is it will only really work for modern browsers.

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/q1qbszdk/)